# Upload file without waiting for its upload and start some other work on the same page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

How can we reduce time at the time of uploading a file from jsp to servlet in apche tomcat and put it in queue and start some other thing at the mean time while uploading of file is going on

Comment: Take a look at this post: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330104/starting-a-new-thread-in-servlet

Answer (score 0):

You can make the call asynchronous using `@Asynchronous`

Answer (score 0):

The server should be able to handle any (reasonable) number of simultaneous requests: just let the upload happen and do something else!

Now, to do that on the "same" page as the upload is not possible if you are using plain-old HTTP POST with a form. Instead, you'll have to use one of those Flash-based upload tools or maybe there is one in Javascipt you can use that will send the upload some other way (XMLHTTPRequest?). Then you can have the upload run but the page itself is still functional.