# Sometimes nothing is printed to servlet's output stream, when inside a scheduled task

Tags: java, servlets, scheduling

I had a need to limit the connection rate (in my servlet) to certain external service and I decided to give ScheduledExecutorService a try. Scheduling itself seems to function just fine, but output gets printed only occasionally - in most cases nothing is outputted. Why does such happen? I'm using Tomcat 7 as a test server.

```
int waitingtimeinmilliseconds = 5000;

ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule() {

    public void run() {

        Fetcher fetcher = new Fetcher(loginname, password);
        List<Item> items = fetcher.fetchItems();
        // do something with the results

        //ServletOutputStream
        out.print("teststring" + items.size());

    }

}, waitingtimeinmilliseconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

Comment: why not simple Thread.sleep(5000)

Comment: Variable 'waitingtimeinmilliseconds' is actually generated by a filter. It will take care that there is always atleast certain amount of time between two connections to an external service (one external service access per servlet thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find very exhaustive description of what is causing your problem in: [HttpServletResponse seems to periodically send prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316904) (also check: [starting a new thread in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330104)).

Basically you cannot use external threads to write to servlet output. Once you leave `doGet()`/`doPost()`, servlet container assumes you are done and discards the output after flushing it to the client. But since you are writing to the stream asynchronously, *sometimes* the output gets through, while other times gets discarded.

If you want your rate limiting to be very scalable, consider `async` servlets (from 3.0). If you just want to throttle some clients, [`RateLimiter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) from [guava](/questions/tagged/guava) will work for you<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - see [RateLimiter - discovering Google Guava](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2012/09/ratelimiter-discovering-google-guava.html) on my blog.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at that post.

I just noticed that if the servlet doesn't seem to output anything for my AJAX-based GUI to consume, I might see the wanted output right before <!DOCTYPE html>, if I refresh the browser.

Later I might have to choose a PaaS-provider, which doesn't support Tomcat 7 (just Tomcat 6), which support only Servlet spesification 2.5, but I will seriously consider using asyncronous servlets.

Comment: I now understand that it was about race condition. However, by using asyncronous servlets and outputting inside AsyncListeners's onComplete-method I am now left with a situation, where everything functions just fine (output is always exactly what is suppose to be).

I'd like add that it wasn't enough to add "asyncSupported = true" to the WebServlet-annotation. I had to set following attribute:
    req.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);

Comment: Here's simple example about using asyncronous servlets (very useful feature): http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=1437

Comment: @MarkoSeppänen: I never had to use this special attribute, however I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855712). Note that once you started async processing you can write to `OutputStream` at any time from any thread. Not necessarily from `onComplete()`.